# instant search with jquery and spring mvc

Tags: spring, search, live

I need some help with jquery or other scripts for instant search. 
I have basic knowledge of jquery. And I use Spring MVC as the back end program.

In my page I need to search for two users and the result must bee shown on the same search page.

My question are: Must I use PHP for connecting to database? Is PHP working with spring?

Any example any where using live search with jquery and  spring?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a post about integration jQuery / AJAX / Spring MVC.
You can read it @ http://stories.stefanocazzola.it/2012/07/spring-and-json-requests.html

Hope this can help you out,

Stefano

Comment: Hi As I wrote I don't have any knowledge of Ajax, and in your code you have // some code to show the employes. How can I show the users then? Do you have any more code? Thanks

Comment: Did you check out the full code? The link is provided in the post. It's a Spring Roo project so you'd better open it with Spring Tools Suite (STS). Or install Spring extensions in your Eclipse.

Comment: Another good resource you could read: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look into 
[JavaScript dynamic language support in Spring framework](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/09/javascript-dynamic-language-support-in.html)

and [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

"Is PHP working with spring": No it does not.

As far as the code goes, I create something over the weekend.